# Kotlin Exposed/Postgresql is lower-casing my table name in queries; how to use capitalized table names?

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have the following SQL query using Kotlin Exposed to a Postgres server with a capitalized table name:

```
object Table: IntIdTable("Table") {
    val tC = text("Text")
    val vC = text("Value")
}

Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://...", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver")
transaction {
    logger.addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
    val query = Table.select {
        Table.id eq 5
    }
    query.forEach {
        println( it[Table.tC] )
    }
}
```

But I am getting back:
     `Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table" does not exist`

Usually I would simply be able to quote the table name `"Table"` to use the capitalized table names, but can't seem to do that with Kotlin Exposed; so is there a way to use the capitalized table name by preventing it from being lowercased?

Comment: Another good example why using quoted identifiers is a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by using escaped quotes within the table string, example for the above question would be as follows:

```
object Table : IntIdTable("\"Table\"") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the whole sample and point to the place where the exception is thrown? From the current code that's unclear who and how trying to create `relation` to the table.